# What wrong with pointwise convergent

Tags: analysis

It is true that the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous as it has proved as a theorem, but what is wrong with pointwise limit? I mean why this theorem it doesn't work for if the convergence is pointwise?

Can any one clarify this to me may be using epsilon definition if possible?

Thank you.

Comment: It is a different question to ask why a modified theorem (without "uniform") is false and where a given proof of the original theorem breaks down when applied to the modified theorem. You seem to be interested in the latter, but one cannot answer to that without knowing the proof you are talking about. By the way, if the proof is properly written, the glitch should be easy to spot; just look where the "uniform" hypothesis is used. If the proof is so unclear that finding the use of the hypothesis is difficult, the you can test each claim against a counterexample to the modified theorem.

Comment: An explanation that used to be fairly common in textbooks (but is less common now) involves the idea of "points of infinitely slow convergence". For some references, simultaneously google the phrases "uniform convergence" and "infinitely slow", both as a web search and as a google-books search.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a reasonable question. In the standard $\epsilon/3$ proof of the theorem, you have (with $f_n\to f$)
$$|f(x)-f(a)| \le |f(x)-f_n(x)| + |f_n(x)-f_n(a)| + |f_n(a)-f(a)|\,,$$
and, *using uniform convergence*, you pick $N$ so that $|f_n(z)-f(z)|<\epsilon/3$ for all $n\ge N$. If you have only *pointwise convergence*, you choose an $N$ that works for $a$ but then may well find that you need increasing values of $N$ (going to $\infty$) for different values of $x$ as $x\to a$. You need a fixed such $N$ to get a $\delta$ from the limit definition for $f_N$ to make the middle term $<\epsilon/3$.

If you try to implement the proof with the standard example @Ittay Weiss gave, or many others, you will see precisely what I'm saying here.

Answer (score 1):

The standard example is the sequence of function $f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$, given by $f_n (x)=x^n$. Each function is continuous but the point-wise limit is (easily seen to be) the function $f(x)=0$ if $0\le x<1$ and $f(1)=1$, a discontinuous function.

Comment: Yes that is true, but my question is if you have been asked to prove that or why the theorem doesn't work with pointwise, how you will prove that? I mean not using a particular example but may be use the epsilon definition of pointwise and getting contradiction or I don't actually know??

Comment: the particular example is the proof that the theorem fails with point-wise convergence.

Comment: well, that was what I answerd when I have been asked this question by the lecture, but he still asking me why, what is wrong???

Comment: I don't know exactly what it was that you answered, nor precisely what your lecturer told you. You might want to post a new question with the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can view this as an instance of the question $$
  \lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{m\to\infty} g(n,m) \overset{?}= \lim_{m\to\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} g(n,m) \text{,}
$$
i.e. of the question whether two limit-taking operations can be swapped. If you have a pointwise converging sequence of continuous function $f_n$, simply pick an $x$ and an arbitrary sequence $x_m \to x$, and set $$
  g(n,m) = f_n(x_m) \text{.}
$$
The questionable identity above then becomes \begin{align}
  \underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty} \underbrace{\lim_{m\to\infty} f_n(x_m)}_{=f_n(x) \:\text{($f_n$ continuous!)}}}_{=f(x)\:\text{($f_n\to f$ pointwise!)}}
  &\overset{?}=
  \lim_{m\to\infty} \underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x_m)}_{=f(x_m) \:\text{($f_n\to f$ pointwise!)}} &\Leftrightarrow \\
  f(x) &\overset{?}= \lim_{m\to\infty} f(x_m) \text{,}
\end{align}
which simply asserts that $f$ is continuous at $x$.

So one possible answer to why this fails is because "limits cannot, in general, be swapped".

Comment: Thanks to all for your help