# Visualizing where uniform convergence fails but pointwise convergence holds

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I am well acquainted with the concepts of pointwise and uniform convergence, namely on the former one fixes a point $x$ and then investigates if a given sequence of functions converges. In the latter, one sees if all $x$ can converge "at once". A more intuitive way to frame the latter is one can construct an $\epsilon$-tube around $f$ that contains all functions $f_n$  for all $n \geq N$ for some $N$ (depending on $\epsilon$ of course).

A friend of mine is taking analysis for the first time asked for an analogous image, but instead where pointwise convergence holds yet uniform convergence fails and I fell short. I am hoping someone on here can come up with a better mental picture than I can.

Comment: think of the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ given by $f_n = x^n$ defined on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: @user1090793 Thanks, that's a good one where there is no continuous limiting function.

Comment: Another example is $f_n(x)=\frac1ng(x)$ for some fixed unbounded function $g(x)$. The sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges pointwise to the zero function, but not uniformly. Verifying this should be a good exercise in these definitions.

Comment: *(repeating [comment from 13 May 2013](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/390190/13130))* An explanation that used to be fairly common in textbooks (but is less common now) involves the idea of "points of infinitely slow convergence". For some references, simultaneously google the phrases "uniform convergence" and "infinitely slow", both as a web search and as a google-books search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A canonical example, mentioned in the comments, is $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$. Converges pointwise to $0$ for $x<1$ and to $1$ for $x=1$. The convergence cannot possibly be uniform because a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.

A more illustrative example, in my opinion, is a "travelling bump". Let $f_n=1_{[n,n+1]}$. That is,
$$
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\ n\leq x\leq n+1\\[0.3cm] 0,&\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
Then $f_n\to0$ pointwise, since for any $x$ we will eventually have $x<n$ for $n$ large enough. Meanwhile $\max\{|f_n(x)|: x \}=1$ for all $n$; that is $\operatorname{dist}(f_n,0)=1$ for all $n$, so the convergence is not uniform. Of course the example can be easily modified to have $f_n$ continuous or even smooth.

Comment: That's a very nice example, I hadn't seen that before!

Answer (score 2):

A classic example is a [sigmoid function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function):

$$f(x;n)= \frac{1}{1+e^{-nx}}$$

This function converges to a [Heaviside step function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#:%7E:text=The%20Heaviside%20step%20function%2C%20or,and%20one%20for%20positive%20arguments.) as $n \to \infty$ pointwise but *not* uniformly, since it has a fixed point at $f(0)=\frac12$ — a permanent discontinuity of $\frac12$ from the limiting value at $n=\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A=[0,1)$ and $f_{n}=x^n$, then $f_{n}$ converges pointwise to zero but not uniformly.

[image]

Every point in $[0,1)$ eventually goes to $0$, for instance focus on the grey point, it has an $x$ value very close to $1$, but it still goes to $0$ eventually, the same is true for any point, however together the sequence of functions is **never completely** less than even $0.5$, and so while the sequence converges pointwise to $0$ (as depicted by the grey dot) it does not converge uniformly(since it's always 'stuck' to the point $(1,1)$).